# jQuery Validate form check if date is specific day

Tags: jquery, regex, validation, date

I would like to check if the date value is a sunday or not, but the problem is that my date is on a specific format (dd/mm/yyyy -> 27/06/2017)

I use jQuery Form Validator plugin.

This is my validator for the date format:

```
$.validator.addMethod("myDateFormat", function(value, element) {
        var re = /^\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}$/;
        return (this.optional(element) && value=="") || re.test(value); });
```

And, my validator for the saturday test:

```
$.validator.addMethod("dateUsine", function(value, element) {
    var n = new Date(value);
    var w = n.getDay();
    console.log(w);
    return this.optional(element) || w == 6;
    });
```

And finally, the rules on the field:

```
rules: {
            dateusine: {
                required: true,
                myDateFormat: true,
                dateUsine: true
            },
        }
```

But it doesn't work. An idea, please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your date format is not valid for `Date()`, use `mm/dd/yyyy` format to make it valid.

```js
console.log(new Date('27/06/2017'));
console.log(new Date('06/27/2017'));
```

If you want to get the day from the date format `dd/mm/yyyy` then first convert it in a valid date like,

```
$.validator.addMethod("dateUsine", function(value, element) {
    var v = value.split('/'),
        n = new Date(parseInt(v[2]), parseInt(v[1])-1, parseInt(v[0])); // Date(year,month,date)
        w = n.getDay();
    console.log(w);
    return this.optional(element) || w == 6;
});
```

**Snippet,**

```js
$(function() {
  $.validator.addMethod("dateUsine",function(value,element){
    var v = value.split('/'),
      n = new Date(parseInt(v[2]), parseInt(v[1])-1, parseInt(v[0])); // Date(year,month,date)
    w = n.getDay();
    //console.log(w,n,v);
    return this.optional(element) || w == 6;
  },'It is not Saturday');
  $.validator.setDefaults({
  submitHandler: function() {
   alert("submitted!");
  }
 });

  $('#frm').validate({
    rules: {
      dateinuse: {
        required: true,
        dateUsine: true
      }
    },
    messages: {
      required: 'Enter date',
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.16.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>

<form id="frm" action="">
  <input type="text" id="dateinuse" name="dateinuse" value="25/06/2017"/><br/>
  <input type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need to get the date in the format dd/mm/yyyy and to test if dd is on saturday

Answer (score 0):

You obviously know the format (which is strange though) but anyway.
I would split the string using the "/" as the seperator into an array.
First item in the array is day, second is month, third is year.

You can then create a new Date object using these 3 values.
Note that you need to subtract 1 from month...

```
var dtString = "27/06/2017",
    dtArr = dtString.split("/"),
    dt = new Date(dtArr[2], dtArr[1] - 1, dtArr[0]);
```